Attach to Domain to CF Workers
After following the guide on how to attach a custom domain to Cloudflare Workers, I ran into an issue. I am talking about this article: https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/worker-domain-attach-to-domain
Error:
Error creating DNS record: {
  success: false,
  errors: [ { code: 10000, message: 'Authentication error' } ]
}

Here is my code:
This is the code implementation:
import axios from 'axios';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export const createDNSRecord = async (subdomain: string): Promise<void> => {
    const data = {
        environment: "production",
        hostname: `${subdomain}.subdomain.com`,
        service: process.env.CLOUDFLARE_WORKER_NAME,
        zone_id: process.env.CLOUDFLARE_ZONE_ID
    };
    // ALL ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES ARE WORKING
    console.log('CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID:', process.env.CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID);
    console.log('CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY:', process.env.CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY);
    console.log('CLOUDFLARE_ZONE_ID:', process.env.CLOUDFLARE_ZONE_ID);
    console.log('CLOUDFLARE_WORKER_NAME:', process.env.CLOUDFLARE_WORKER_NAME);
    console.log('data:', data);

    const url = `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/${process.env.CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID}/workers/domains`;

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.put(url, data, { headers });
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('DNS record created successfully.');
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to create DNS record.');
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Error creating DNS record:', error.response.data);
        } else {
            console.error('Error creating DNS record:', error.message);
        }
    }
}

I have given the necessary API permission if I am correct?

Can someone help here?
